# Small leak has appeared in a PVC drain pipe joint, how to seal?

Tags: plumbing, leak, drain, pvc

I have attached a picture of the joint, and circled the bit that is leaking, a small hole. What is the best way to go about sealing this up and fixing it? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they put the primer down without the glue.   Clean area, reprime it, get pvc glue, put glue around and jam it in.

If the length is not great enough to jam in - it looks a little short or something else moved - then cut about a foot up buy a double female straight joint in that size and if you made your cut straight you can probably use the exact same piece!   The joint will give you a good 1-1.5 inches.   You can always get 16" in that size (4?) if you don't want to go back to the store.

This is not a location that normally would EVER leak, so obviously installed wrong.   Should be a 30 minute fix, if that.

Comment: It's a 30 minute fix for someone used to this kind of work. For a non-plumber doing his first repair, budget 2 hours, then add in a fudge factor. Just because that's how projects go for an amateur DIYer. Simply getting the pipe cut in a tight space up against the bottom of the subfloor will take a while when you're rummaging through a limited collection of tools, then standing in front of shelves of alternates at the big-box wondering what other tool will do the job... (Been there. Done that. Got the t-shirt and a collection of random tools...)

Comment: @FreeMan - 30 mins to fix, not shop.   If it takes more than 30 it is being done wrong because at worst this is making 1 cut.   If they do not have a hack saw or a hand saw that will work, they need the $7 variety from HF at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the entire joint has pulled out of the fitting so it is more than just a small leak. You should cut back the pipe that goes into the connector so you can assess the condition inside and then use a new length of pipe and a coupler to reattach to the fitting if it is salvageable.

Comment: You are correct look at the  depth of purple primer on all other joints